# Scrapy return Base64 of Image Url after 10 images

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrap data using scrapy. I have got the textual data as needed.But while i tried to scrap image src its returns me exact url in the start and after some records its return

> "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="

Here is my Spider Code

```
import scrapy
class CoinmarketcapSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'coinmarketcap'
    allowed_domains = ['coinmarketcap.com']
    start_urls = ['https://coinmarketcap.com/2']
    def parse(self, response):
        cointable=response.css('table#currencies').xpath('//tbody/tr')
        for coins in cointable:
            name=coins.css('a.currency-name-container::text').extract_first().strip()
            logo=coins.css('img.logo-sprite::attr(src)').extract()
            symbol=coins.css('span.currency-symbol').xpath('.//a/text()').extract_first().strip()
            market_cap=coins.css('.market-cap').xpath('text()').extract_first().strip()
            yield {
                'Name':name,
                'image_urls':logo,
                'symbol':symbol,
                'market_cap':market_cap
            }
        print response
```

Here the output json file which have ImgLogo url

> [ {"coinName": ["Bitcoin"], "symbol": ["BTC"], "imgLogo":
>   ["https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/1.png"]},
>   {"coinName": ["Ethereum"], "symbol": ["ETH"], "imgLogo":
>   ["https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/1027.png"]},
>   {"coinName": ["XRP"], "symbol": ["XRP"], "imgLogo":
>   ["https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/52.png"]},
>   {"coinName": ["Bitcoin Cash"], "symbol": ["BCH"], "imgLogo":
>   ["https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/1831.png"]},
>   {"coinName": ["EOS"], "symbol": ["EOS"], "imgLogo":
>   ["https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/1765.png"]},
>   {"coinName": ["Stellar"], "symbol": ["XLM"], "imgLogo":
>   ["https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/512.png"]},
>   {"coinName": ["Litecoin"], "symbol": ["LTC"], "imgLogo":
>   ["https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/2.png"]},
>   {"coinName": ["Tether"], "symbol": ["USDT"], "imgLogo":
>   ["https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/825.png"]},
>   {"coinName": ["Cardano"], "symbol": ["ADA"], "imgLogo":
>   ["https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/2010.png"]},
>   {"coinName": ["Monero"], "symbol": ["XMR"], "imgLogo":
>   ["https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/328.png"]},
>   {"coinName": ["IOTA"], "symbol": ["MIOTA"], "imgLogo":
>   ["data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="]},
>   {"coinName": ["TRON"], "symbol": ["TRX"], "imgLogo":
>   ["data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="]},
>   {"coinName": ["Dash"], "symbol": ["DASH"], "imgLogo":
>   ["data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="]}]

Here is my Items.py code

```
import scrapy
class CmindexItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
     image_urls = scrapy.Field()
```

Here is my piplines.py code that download images and save them in my images directory

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem


class CmindexPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        item['image_paths'] = image_paths
        return item
```

Here is my settings.py code

```
BOT_NAME = 'cmindex'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['cmindex.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'cmindex.spiders'
USER_AGENT = 'cmindex (+http://www.cmindex.com)'
# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'cmindex.pipelines.CmindexPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE ='E:\WorkPlace\cmindex\cmindex\img'
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
}
```

I had added fake user agents and also had added delay in the requests but it didn't affect my end result. So if anyone have idea please share. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please remove follwing from your settings.py

```
USER_AGENT = 'cmindex (+http://www.cmindex.com)'
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
}
```

And also Unfollow Robotstxt

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

And please made following changes in your spider file.
After viewing the source of coinmarketcap i had found that after 10 rows Src of Image is binary So simple then get Data-src of Image instead of src.

```
import scrapy
class CoinmarketcapSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'coinmarketcap'
allowed_domains = ['coinmarketcap.com']
start_urls = ['https://coinmarketcap.com/']
def parse(self, response):

    cointable=response.css('table#currencies').xpath('//tbody/tr')
    for coins in cointable:
        name=coins.css('a.currency-name-container::text').extract_first().strip()
        logoData = coins.css('img.logo-sprite::attr(data-src)').extract()
        logoSrc=coins.css('img.logo-sprite::attr(src)').extract()
        if(logoData==[]):
            logo=logoSrc
        else:
            logo=logoData



        symbol=coins.css('span.currency-symbol').xpath('.//a/text()').extract_first().strip()
        market_cap=coins.css('.market-cap').xpath('text()').extract_first().strip()
        yield {
            'Name':name,
            'image_urls':logo,
            'symbol':symbol,
            'market_cap':market_cap,
        }
    print(response)
```

Comment: that's what i was missing. Thanks  for your time . Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

The `data:image/gif;base64,R0l...` **is** the full image encoded in base64.

Check out mozillas documentation on [data-uris](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs):

> Data URLs, URLs prefixed with the data: scheme, allow content creators to embed small files inline in documents.

and

> Data URLs are composed of four parts: a prefix (data:), a MIME type indicating the type of data, an optional base64 token if non-textual, and the data itself:

```
data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
```

In your case mediatype is: `image/gif`, encoded in `base64` and your actual image is `R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==`

You can decode it with python's `base64` package:

```
with open('foo.gif', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(base64.b64decode("R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="))
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is the relevant raw html which you would get from the response.

Html snippet for a coin in the first 10 rows

```
10
</td>
<td class="no-wrap currency-name" data-sort="Tether">
<img src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/825.png" class="logo-sprite" alt="Tether" height="16" width="16">
```

Html snippet for a coin after the 10th row

```
11
</td>
<td class="no-wrap currency-name" data-sort="TRON">
<img data-src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/1958.png" class="logo-sprite lazyload" alt="TRON" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" height="16" width="16">
```

Basically the server is sending two different format for data. One for row 1-10 and other for row > 10. As is row 1-10 get the src attribute but row 11th onwards you are getting src attribute as base64 and data-src attribute. But I can see that data-src attribute is finally getting applied to the src attribute on the browser side of things.

Next question should be why it is doing that ?

I think the intention here is to show data as quickly as possible, something akin to progressive load. I can't speculate about the effectiveness of this scheme, may be you have page size of 10 in some display format too.

So basically row 1-10 have final html for browser rendering but row 11th onwards the magic happens with java script. Now the java script is minified and compressed but I assume the following snippets(using image for better representation) is transferring the value of data-src attribute to src attribute. 
[image: data-src definition]
[image: Setting src value from data-src]

Having said all this I think the safe way to scrap is use

1. Use the attribute value of data-src
2. If data-src is not available use
   src attribute.

And this is the source or html which the scrappy would be seeing. 
[image]

Also the src for the row 11 and more with "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" is kind of placed holder image I think, all of them are same, and it seems 1x1 pixel.

Comment: data-src isn't available for initial images it returns empty result that's why i was using src for it.

Comment: Yes, If it is not available fall back on src. That way you are sure to be consistent in getting the right url. I just formatted my answer, which basically says this.

Comment: Sorry but it have same values in src and data-src

Comment: No, in the raw html which scrappy would be getting( or see the source in chrome or firefox you can do wget or curl), for row1-10 you would have src attribute with url. For the row 11 onwards, you will have data-src with the url. So basically if you use data-src and if not present src you should be fine.

Comment: Please see, the edited answer showing the source html, which the scrappy would be seeing.